# PHP paypal webhook REST

Tags: php, paypal, webhooks

I am trying to implement a paypal webhook for recurring payment, but I am stuck at finding the right documentation, there is like 5 pages on paypal for webhooks. I found this one : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/webhooks/rest/ , there is nothing about it being deprecated or something. After following the Integration steps it led me to install the paypal rest sdk. But when I open it on github it says that it is deprecated ?? https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK . Does anyone know how to implement it, with non deprecated sdk ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SDKs mentioned in that guide are deprecated, direct API calls are not deprecated, and are how it should be implemented.

It's all documented on the page you linked, there is this API reference: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/webhooks/v1/

Comment: Oh, thanks I am so sorry for asking such a dumb question, but I am so lost in the documentation. :)

Comment: Not a dumb question - the Paypal docs for PHP webhook is terrible (non-existent)